# PHPSpreadsheet - How do I return a row containing a specific value?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

So I'm currently using PHPSpreadsheet to read and display an excel file in a datatable, my issue is I'm trying to make a viewable version of that row with extended data when clicked into, but just can't seem to wrap my head around it, any advice would be great

I've got it working by coordinates by it just won't work for what I'm trying/hoping to achieve

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share some existing code that will help us understand your problem. Also read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.